# Flask app on Heroku keeps booting workers

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app running on Heroku. Until yesterday everything worked fine.
Now for some reason today, the web app keeps booting workers:

```
2017-09-28T07:02:06.869090+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:06 +0000] [3882] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3882
2017-09-28T07:02:07.308558+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:07 +0000] [3899] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3899
2017-09-28T07:02:07.626838+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:07 +0000] [3901] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3901
2017-09-28T07:02:07.906617+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:07 +0000] [3909] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3909
2017-09-28T07:02:08.701473+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:08 +0000] [3926] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3926
2017-09-28T07:02:08.890857+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:08 +0000] [3928] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3928
2017-09-28T07:02:09.543447+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:09 +0000] [3936] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3936
2017-09-28T07:02:10.724376+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:10 +0000] [3946] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3946
2017-09-28T07:02:11.771921+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:11 +0000] [3962] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3962
2017-09-28T07:02:11.830635+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-09-28 07:02:11 +0000] [3963] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3963
```

Of course now the app cannot work normally anymore, any requests sent to it is timed-out.
Here is the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

And the requirement.txt:

```
scipy
numpy
flask
gunicorn
pillow
tensorflow
```

The app works fine when I run it locally with the command:

```
heroku local web
```

I have submitted a ticket to Heroku, but in case anybody can help here it would save me a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: I've just came across the same problem. But in my case, the issue occurred in a Docker container, and restarting the container alone won't fix the problem, I have to stop and start a new independent container.